# Unable to access UIView subclass IBOutlets From TabBarController

Tags: swift, swift4, addsubview

I have a UIView Class with xib. I try to add it in another ViewControllers as a popover view. I have outlet connections. But when I run the application it crashed and stated

> This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key btnAbtUs

I think the problem is should select delegate. I may using wrong way to add this xib. How can I correct it?

Here is my code.

my `UIView` subclass

```
class MoreView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnAboutUs: UIButton!

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        loadViewFromNib()
    }

    func loadViewFromNib() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "MoreView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.insertSubview(view, at: 0)
        commitInit()
    }

    private func commitInit(){
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        self.btnAboutUs.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickAboutUs(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    class func instanceFromNib() -> UIView {
        return UINib(nibName: "MoreView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
    }

    @objc func clickAboutUs(_ sender: Any) {
        print("tap")
    }
}
```

in `UITabBarController`

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    
    let moreView = MoreView.instanceFromNib
    
    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController,
        navigationController.viewControllers.contains(where: { $0 is MoreViewController }) {
        moreView().frame.origin.y = 100
        self.view.addSubview(moreView())
        
        return false
    } else  {
        moreView().removeFromSuperview()
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because you have set the class name as UIView for the wired connection.

Comment: so how should it be.Will i need to set it as UIViewController?

Comment: can you ctrl click on the outlet in the xib , and check if something have more than one connection @Saravanan ?

Comment: Checked and its have only one connection. Can you please look at the code in the Should change Delegate. is there any mistake I made? @Mohammad S

Comment: @Saravanan Please make a connection from `UIView` itself by right click on it you might be did it from `File's Owner`. Also right click on `File's Owner` and `UIView` and check there should not be any yellow warning.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have an another issue. I was using wrong way to add the UIView now working perpectly @TheTiger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the issue. This is the right way to add a UIView as a SubView controller of a UIViewController.

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController,
        navigationController.viewControllers.contains(where: { $0 is MoreViewController }) {
        let mySubView : MoreView
        mySubView = MoreView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 667) )
        self.view.addSubview(mySubView)
        return false
    } else  {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have copied the XIB and forgot to remove/add a connection with the IBOutlet. Please check.

It indicates that an already connected Interface Builder object is removed/renamed in its owner's source (File's Owner).

Comment: I have checked and reconnect all my outlets. if I run the project with out add outlet its working.But when I add the Outlet it got crashed

Comment: try to check all the post from there : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/what-does-this-mean-nsunknownkeyexception-reason-this-class-is-not-key-v . It really seems to be a bad connection, renaming, or file-owner problem at first glance

Answer (score 0):

You may forgot to remove a connection with the IBOutlet. Please check on on show connection inspector.First click on file inspector of xib then click on show connection inspector. Shown in image.

[image]

Remove the broken outlets.

Comment: I have checked there is no issue in the outlets. I think the problem is in Delegate method. self.view.addsubview() may cause this issue. Will you pls look at this delegate?

Comment: @Saravanan Remove "private" from private func commitInit()  . this may be cuasing the issue

Comment: now what you can finally do is create the button outlets again